# How do I change the border radius for multiple points at the same time in the new Adobe Illustrator CC 2018?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, corners

Since the last update of Illustrator the interface has become very clean. The border radius functionality has disappeared and can be accessed by double clicking in one corner but it's a pain now to just change al border radii in one single stroke.

Any ideas? Or am I missing a feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the feature is moved inside the transform panel ;)

Comment: And you can get to that by double clicking the handle by any of the corners.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the Properties panel. In Window menu select Properties.

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/edit-rounded-rectangles.html

Answer (score 0):

If you single click the little circular handle near the corner you can change the border radius of all corners.
If you instead double click the handle you only edit the selected corner.

Also when you double click the transform panel should appear, where you can change the radius more precisely.